# Going from C code to RISC-V assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, riscv

I have this exercise

> *Translate the following C code to RISC-V assembly code. Assume that the values of a, b, i, and j are in registers x5, x6, x7, and x29, respectively. Also, assume that register x10 holds the base address of the array D.*

```
for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    for(j=0; j<b; j++){
        D[4*j] = i + j;
    }
}
```

I also have the solution with comments

```
Loop1:
    addi x7, x0, 0      // i = 0
    bge  x7, x5, ENDi   // while i < a
    addi x30, x10, 0    // x30 = &D[0]
    addi x29, x0, 0     // j = 0
Loop2:
    bge x29, x6, ENDj   // while j < b
    add x31, x7, x29    // x31 = i + j
    sd  x31, 0(x30)     // D[4*j] = x31
    addi x30, x30, 32   // x30 = &D[4*(j+1)]
    addi x29, x29, 1    // j++
    jal  x0,  LOOP2
ENDj:
    addi x7, x7, 1      // i++
    jal  x0, LOOP1
ENDi:
```

**What  I don't understand**

```
sd  x31, 0(x30)     // D[4*j] = x31
addi x30, x30, 32   // x30 = &D[4*(j+1)]
```

Doesn't `sd x31, 0(x30)` mean that I store the value of x31 in the 0'th bit of array 30? Where does the 4*j all of a sudden come from?

And doesn't `addi x30, x30, 32`  mean that x30 = x30+32? And wasn't x30 = &D[0] defined in the first loop? How does j all of a sudden come into contact with x30?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to the following:

```
for(int64_t i=0; i<a; i++){
    int64_t* x30 = &D[0];
    for(int64_t j=0; j<b; j++){
        *x30 = i + j;
        x30 += 4; // increment by 4 elements
    }
}
```

x30 is used as a 'current pointer' in the loop. It points to the relevant element in the D array. It is initialized to the first element, and is incremented in steps of 4 elements, which emulates the 4*j part. Since your elements are 64-bit, 8 bytes, to increment by 4 elements the underlying address of the pointer should be incremented by 4*8=32 bytes.

It is often more efficient to maintain a current pointer than recompute it everytime, especially in RISC-V, because you cannot have a register offset (there is no `str x31, [x30, x29]`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still confused. Can you elaborate what the code ```sd x31, 0(x30)``` does? Because I can't see the relationship between the code and the comment in the solution.

Comment: @Carl `sd x31, 0(x30)` is literally store x31 at the address in x30, so `*x30 = x31` in C, store to element pointed by x30, which is equivalent to `x30[0] = x31` (* makes more sense for pointers, and [] for arrays).

Comment: Okay, I guess it's just that comment saying that ```D[4*j] = x31``` that is confusing me.

Comment: @Carl This is pointer arithmetic. `D[4*j]` in C is equivalent to `*(&D + 4*j)`. So instead of computing `&D + 4*j` each loop, you start with `x30 = &D`, then each loop, when `j += 1`, do `x30 += 4`.

Comment: @Carl But yeah the comments are not describing exactly what the assembly is doing, they are describing what it is equivalent to.

Comment: I just don't understand how we can progress in the array elements. The code ```sd  x31, 0(x30)``` doesn't involve j. 0(x30) will always refer to x30[0] won't it?

Comment: @Carl x30 is incremented at the same time as j to progress in the array. Using j, the accesses will be `D[0]`, `D[4]`, `D[8]`... The index to D is incremented by 4 elements each loop, so having x30 starts at &D, and being incremented by 4 elements each loop is equivalent. Basically, it is doing `D[0]; D+=4`, `D[0]; D+=4` , `D[0]; D+=4`. When you increment `x30`, which initially pointed to D[0], you make it point to the following elements, so `x30 = &D[0]` with `x30 += 4` means x30 points to D[4].

Comment: This ```D[0]; D+=4```! This is the crucial point I have trouble understanding. D is an array, and D[0] is the 0'th element of D. But what does ```D+=4``` mean? What does it mean to increment the array? Does it affect the address? Do we move 4 address blocks and then look at the 0'th element of that block?

Comment: @Carl If D is an array you can't really do `D+=4`, but in C (and assembly), there is almost no difference between arrays and pointers. If you use a pointer instead, as in `int64_t* x30 = &D[0];`, then x30 points to D[0], and doing `x30 += 4;` each loop will allow you to access `D[0]`, `D[4]`, `D[8]`... Each array element is consecutive in memory. So taking the address/pointer to the first element, then incrementing it will allow you to access the next elements in the array.

Comment: @Carl: Optimizing `D[j*4]` into `ptr+=4` is related to "strength reduction".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction.  You're replacing shift / add address-generation calculation in the loop with just a pointer increment.  It's even more important if the multiplier wasn't a simple power of 2 (because shifts are still relatively cheap, i.e. not that "strong"), but it's still a case of reducing multiple operations to one.